# Group values conditionally in data frame in R

Tags: r, algorithm, loops, dataframe

Colleagues

I have the following problem. My data-set looks like this:

```
Article = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","C")
Value = c(1,5,2,1,20,18,5,6,3,31,99)
df = data.frame(Article, Value)
```

My goal is to match the highest Value per Article with the lowest Value per Article exhaustively (ignoring middle values), e.g. 1 with 100, 2 with 99, 3 with 98 and etc. And to assign groups for these matches.

The final result for this data frame has to match first row with Article "A" with second row of Article "A", because the first row Value is 1 (and it is the lowest) and second row Value is 5 (and it is the highest). For this pair the algorithm has to assign a similar group, e.g. "A_1". Then the algorithm looks what rows for Article "A" are left and repeats the assignment process - we have only two rows left so it matches them into "A_2".

After that the algorithm jumps into rows with Article = "B" and so on.

The final result has to look like this:

```
Group = c("A_1","A_1", "A_2","A_2", "B_1", "B_NA", "B_1", "C_2", "C_1", "C_2", "C_1")
df = data.frame(Article, Value, Group)
```

My idea (I do not know how to code it yet) is a bit strange:

For N in Article I want to sort the data frame segment ascending (e.g. filter the data frame for only Article N and sort this segment ascending) and assign to first row's Group value = "N_1". Then assign the last row of the segment value = "N_1". Next filter this segment for rows that do not have an assigned value in Group variable yet and repeat the assignment for first and last value. And so on until the algorithm gives groups for all rows in a segment, then it jumps to another value in N.

Can somebody advices me on this problem? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: can we step back a bit and ask what you are trying to do with your data in a broader sense? there might be a better way...

Comment: @roman e.g. Value means somewhat like a stock in the store for a particular Article. The goal is to create a script that will tell me that there is a store with 90 pcs when I have a store with 0 pcs. After that an exsiting script will use the groups (pairs) detected to optimize the inventory (to avrage it between the stores)

Comment: Are we missing a column like `StoreID`, else the current mapping is not congruent, for instance for article C how do you explain the mapping `C_2,C_1,C_2,C_1`, Value 6 and 31 are between the extremes (3,99) so shouldn't the mapping be `C_NA,C_1,C_NA,C_1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works provided that the `value` column of each group does not have any duplicate.

```
f_lbl <- function(x, i){
    l <- length(x)
    mid <- floor(l/2)
    lbl <- names(ls)[i]
    a <- paste0(lbl, "_" , rep(NA, l))
    a[1:mid] <- paste0(lbl,"_",1:mid)
    a[l:(l-mid+1)] <- paste0(lbl,"_",1:mid)
    return(a[match(x, sort(x))])
}

ls <- with(df, split(Value, Article))
df$Group <- unlist(sapply(seq_along(ls), function(i) f_lbl(ls[[i]],i)))

   # Article Value Group
# 1        A     3   A_2
# 2        A     5   A_1
# 3        A     2   A_2
# 4        A     1   A_1
# 5        B    20   B_1
# 6        B    18  B_NA
# 7        B     5   B_1
# 8        C     6   C_2
# 9        C     3   C_1
# 10       C    31   C_2
# 11       C    99   C_1
```

Answer (score 0):

ok so you could then do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
high_and_low <- df %>%
  group_by(Article) %>%
  summarise(high = max(Value),
            low = min(Value))
```

which just pulls out the high and low values for each block. if you needed other info associated with the rows in which the high/low values are found then you could get that too.

is this getting you anywhere closer?